# Adjust child size based on number of children

Tags: css

I want to make a UI that is similar to tabs in a browser.

To this end, I have elements with this CSS:

```
width: 20%;
max-width: 150px;
```

Nice and simple, responsive and awesome.

Only supports five tabs, though. If I want to support 10 tabs, it's as easy as changing to `width: 10%`.

So basically, I want something like:

```
width: calc(100% / number-of-children)
```

If such a thing were possible, that'd be amazing.

I'm currently just using JavaScript to set the width to the above expression. Simple, functional, but I figured I'd ask if anyone knows of a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `CSS3` you may use `display: flex`. E.g.

markup

```
<section>
  <div>tab 1</div>
  <div>tab 2</div>
  <div>tab 3</div>
  <div>tab 4</div>
</section>
```

Css

```
section {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGbpH/

Comment: Elegantly written solution.

Comment: Wow... I've used flex in the past, how could I have forgotten? XD Oh right... because I dropped it in favour of JS-calculated widths because Chrome was dismally failing at them... Maybe it's fixed by now. Anyways, thanks for reminding me of this.

Answer (score 2):

`display: table` is your friend.

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pVr6m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 there's a function called calc() so you can use

```
width: calc(100% / 10);
```

[Here you can find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) documentation and which browser support it ;)

Comment: I think his problem is to know in advance the number of the tabs